# File upload with Jquery.fileupload.js in CodeIgniter - I can't find my error

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, blueimp

The issue is I can't upload file to the folder but the file name is storing in DB. I am getting an image if I copy and paste an image to the folder but I can't able to upload while update or add an image.

I not good in jQuery. Also, this project using Jquery.file upload plugin which I really don't know.

### product-edit.php

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <table id="files" class="files">
          <tr>
              <td>
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                  <img style="width: 300px; height: 200px;"  src="<?= base_url() ?>userfiles/product/<?php echo $product['image'] . '?c=' . rand(1, 9999) ?>"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 my-2" > <?php echo $product['image'] ?> </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 my-2" >
                    <a class="btn-danger btn-sm px-1 " data-url="<?= base_url() ?>products/file_handling?op=delete&name=<?php echo $product['image'] ?>" class="aj_delete">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash mx-1  "></i>Delete Image</a>
                 </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
               <span class="my-2">Select files...</span>
     <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
                   <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]">
               </span>
               <div class="my-1">
                   <q>Allowed: gif, jpeg, png</q>
               </div>
               <!-- The global progress bar -->
               <div id="progress" class="progress">
                   <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

### jQuery

```
<script src="<?php echo assets_url('assets/myjs/jquery.ui.widget.js'); $invoice['tid'] = 0; ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo assets_url('assets/myjs/jquery.fileupload.js') ?>"></script>

$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = '<?php echo base_url() ?>products/file_handling?id=<?php echo $product['pid'] ?>';
   $('#fileupload').fileupload({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      formData: {'<?=$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>': crsf_hash},
      done: function (e, data) {
      var img = 'default.png';

      $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {

      $('#files').html('<tr><td><a data-url="<?php echo base_url() ?>products/file_handling?op=delete&name=' + file.name + '" class="aj_delete"><i class="btn-danger btn-sm icon-trash-a"></i> ' + file.name + ' </a><img style="max-height:200px;" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>userfiles/product/' + file.name + '"></td></tr>');

      img = file.name;
     });

     $('#image').val(img);
        },
     progressall: function (e, data) {
       var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
         $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
           'width',
           progress + '%'
          );
      }
   }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
   .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
 });
```

Here the controller method for upload file to the folder

### Products.php

```
public function file_handling()
    {

        if ($this->input->get('op')) {
            $name = $this->input->get('name');
            if ($this->products->meta_delete($name)) {
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'Success'));
            }
        } else {
            $id = $this->input->get('id');
            $this->load->library("Uploadhandler_generic", array(
                'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i', 'max_file_size' => 2048, 'upload_dir' => FCPATH . 'userfiles/product/', 'upload_url' => base_url() . 'userfiles/product/'
            ));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any console/php error?

Comment: no error on console or alert. even if I place image with name as DB then it is showing image too but don't uploading image.

Comment: yeah .. i got issue .. i think my controller giving me error
like:
{"files":[{"name":"704635default.png","size":false,"type":"image\/png","error":"File upload aborted","deleteUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/jewel\/index.php?file=704635default.png","deleteType":"DELETE"}]}

but I don't know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984581/dealing-with-concurrent-aborted-uploads-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are loading the upload library config but are not actually processing the upload.

After this, which loads the upload library wih your configuration:

```
$this->load->library("Uploadhandler_generic", array(
                'accept_file_types' => '/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i', 'max_file_size' => 2048, 'upload_dir' => FCPATH . 'userfiles/product/', 'upload_url' => base_url() . 'userfiles/product/'
            ));
```

You need to actually process the upload:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
  // do something if the upload processing fails. You can output the errors using $this->upload->display_errors()
}

else
{
  // do something if the upload is successful
  // upload data will be stored in $this->upload->data()
}
```

By doing this, Codeigniter will take the file from your server's `tmp` directory and do with it what you want (such as moving it to its destination). Change `userfile` for the name of the file field.

Please note that if you need to process multiple files at once you'll need to loop through all files (which means a little tweaking on the above code)